# how to catch exception thrown from ts?

Tags: node.js, typescript

So I have written a function in typescript as follows:

userUtils.ts

```
export async function update(id:string, userDetails:Object) {

    return await User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: id}, userDetails, (err, response) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error : ', err);
            throw new Error ("error in your request");
        }

    });   
}
```

In the controller file in nodejs I'm calling the function to update the user collection as follows:

```
 try {
    userUtils.update(id, userDetails).then(function (err, answer) {
      res.status(200).json(answer);
    }).catch(function (e) {
      log.error('User update error : ', e);
      errors.handleError(res, {"error": "error in your request"});
    });
  } catch (e){
      log.error('error : ', e);

  }
```

Now the problem is, I sent the userId that does not exist. Mongo returns cast error and in the ts I have thrown an exception for that. The function in my nodejs controller doesnt catch the exception. How can this be written so that exception are caught and the front application gets a proper response ?

The thrown error is not caught by either catch and is returned to line res.json(); where on logging err and answer both is undefined.

Comment: Can't you check in your controller if the err is not undefined and in case it is not return `res.status(500).json(err)`?

Comment: In the controller, its returned to line res.status(200).json(answer); where err and answer both as undefined.